# GeometryReader Size Calculations SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, geometry, swiftui, macos-catalina

I am attempting to use the GeometryReader to place a view. I used the GeometryReader to
modify a Rectangle() and it is placed as I expected. However, I want to programmatically
set the y value to line up with the top of the VStack frame. I thought I could read
the geometry height of the text field and use it, but I cannot assign the geometry
dimension of the textField to a variable, even though I use the same concept to move
the Rectangle.

Pictorially:
[image]
The simple code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var textHeight = 0.0

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Text("Title Text")
                    }
                //self.textHeight = CGFloat(geometry.size.height)
            }.border(Color.green)

            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                    .path(in: CGRect(x: geometry.size.width - 50,
                                     y: 0, width: geometry.size.width / 2.0,
                                     height: geometry.size.height / 2))
                    .fill(Color.red)
            }

        }.frame(width: 150, height: 300).border(Color.black)
    }
}
```

Xcode Beta 7, Catalina Beta 7
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `VStack` with two `GeometryReader` inside. The `VStack` positions its children vertically, one above the other. The `y=0` of your second `GeometryReader` is the first y *after* the first `GeometryReader`. I suggest you change the way you're designing your UI, for example you can get the same result this way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .path(in: CGRect(x: geometry.size.width - 50, y: 0, width: geometry.size.width / 2.0, height: geometry.size.height / 4))
                        .fill(Color.red)

                    Text("Title Text")
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/2.0)
                        .border(Color.green)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 150, height: 300).border(Color.black)
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

To push things up and down or to the left/right you can use the really useful `Spacer` view.

This is my advice, but if you *really* need to use two `GeometryReader` you have to do this way:

```
struct ContentView2: View {

    @State private var textHeight = CGFloat(0)

    private func firstContentView(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        textHeight = geometry.size.height
        return Text("Title Text")
            .position(x: geometry.size.width/2.0, y: geometry.size.height/2.0)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                self.firstContentView(geometry: geometry)                    
            }.border(Color.green)

            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                    .path(in: CGRect(x: geometry.size.width - 50, y: -self.textHeight, width: geometry.size.width / 2.0, height: geometry.size.height / 2))
                    .fill(Color.red)
            }
        }.frame(width: 150, height: 300).border(Color.black)
    }
}
```

But it's a pretty dirty solution.